# How to read and write a file at /data/system/ location in android device?

Tags: android, android-source, android-file

I am developing a system app. And for that, I want to read and write a file in XML format at **/data/system/** dir.

Is my app still need to have read/ write permission even it is the system app?

I am not sure if it is even possible accessing this location.

Note - With root access I can read the file and can open in terminal.

Comment: Just try. Use normal copy file code. Then tell us.

Answer (score 1):

There are two restrictions for /data/system:

1. File permission. /data/system's owner and group is system(uid:1000). Only the app with system uid can write /data/system.
   `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`
2. Sepolicy. /data/system is labeled with system_data_file. A few domain can access system_data_file, such as system_server, zygote. You need to define an new domain for your app, and add rules to allow the new domain to access system_data_file.

Answer (score 0):

for read/write on that location the device will be **rooted**.
also you have permission can`t do it, because the permission allow you to read/write on /mnt/sdcard

Comment: Actually programtically I will do read and write in a system app.